# How to create alerts on big query schedule jobs and send email on failure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-monitoring

I have multiple big query schedule jobs which gets triggered using a cloud function. How do I set an alert and send am email when any of the big query schedule job fails.

I did look at stackdriver monitoring and tried to create and alert using alerting policy. While creating a metric, I select resource type as "cloud function", metric as "Log entries". In filter, I added function name, region but not sure as what should be the additional Filter to select a log which is when cloud function fails? I have added severity as "ERROR". The configuration is as below

[image]

[image]

[image]

The cloud function failed for some reason and it didn't trigger the big query schedule job. I got 2 emails with one as "ALERT' alert firing and one as "RESOLVED" alert recovered.

[image]

Is this correct? The parameters that I have provided are they enough?

Also, Will the alert be sent even when schedule big query that is triggered from the cloud function fails? I didn't find anything specific to big query schedule query in resource type.

Comment: Did you have a look to cloud alerting?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I have edited my post and provided the details of what I tried after sending this post. However, I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it and also, I did not find anything specific to big query schedule job in resource type while setting the policy. Will the alert policy on cloud function that triggers big query schedule query enough? Or is there any specific resource type that I can use while creating this alert. This question is specifically for schedule queries that are time triggered .

Comment: It looks like you managed to solve the issue by yourself since you're getting the alerts based on log based metrics. Or is there other question or something is not clear ? If so please state your question directly.

Comment: @Wojtek_B, this works for cloud function which in turn triggers my big query schedule query. What I wanted to know is how do I set up an alert policy for a big query schedule job that is scheduled on a particular time and is not triggered by cloud function. I am not able to set up an alert for this type.

Comment: You have to create a log based metric that will utilize any logs that are collected while running the job. Have you tried that ?